# Zend Framework cookie management

Tags: php, zend-framework, cookies

i want to know if Zend Framework has any class for handling cookies. a class that wraps php's `setcookie()` function for example.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15):

[`Zend_Http_Cookie`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.http.cookies.html) is just a component to create RFC compatible cookie strings and to test a cookie against a given HTTP request scenario. Its primary purpose is to assist in cookie-scenarios with [`Zend_Http_Client`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.http.html) in the `Zend_Http` package.

I assume that you're looking for a wrapper set cookies - perhaps compared to `Zend_Session`. There currently is no such component to assist you with creating cookies ([`setcookie()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) is the right way to go). To read cookies you can resort to the appropriate method [`Zend_Controller_Request_Http`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.request.html#zend.controller.request.http)`::getCookie($key = null, $default = null)`.

Comment: yah, i was looking for a wrapper set cookies. i will use php's setcookie functions. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 12):

If you wan't for example $_COOKIE['foo'] you use

```
$this->getRequest()->getCookie('foo');
```

What I've talked in #zftalk @freenode PHP's own `setcookie()` is correct way to set client's cookie.