# working with cookie in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

How can I write a cookie for user_name and password and read it back if the cookie is already there in zend framework.I read the manual but not getting it. I'm really stuck, plz help.

Thanks

Comment: there are lot of [examples](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.http.cookies.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Zend_Http_Cookie is not a good thing for setting/getting normal cookies. Read about it here [php setcookie vs Zend_Http_Cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883658/php-setcookie-vs-zend-http-cookie) and [Zend Framework cookie management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961596/zend-framework-cookie-management). There is nothing wrong with using native PHP `setcookie()` for setting and using the superglobal array `$_COOKIE` for getting cookies.