# Zend Framework 2 - How to check if a cookie exists?

Tags: php, cookies, zend-framework2

How can I check if a cookie already exists?

I tried:

```
if (!$this->getRequest()->getCookie()->offsetExists('cookiename')) {
    // cookie exists
}
```

But when the cookie does not yet exist, I get the following error:

> Call to a member function offsetExists() on a non-object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you have to grab the cookie first and check if its actually there.

```
$cookie = $this->getRequest()->getCookie();

if (empty($cookie) || !$cookie->offsetExists('cookiename')) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [official documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.http.request.html) and [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961596/zend-framework-cookie-management), you can check if a cookie exists like so:

```
if (!empty($this->getRequest()->getCookie('foo'))) {
    // cookie exists, do your stuff
}
```

Comment: I don't know why but this didn't work for me. Thx anyway.